# Design text look like it is cut out and casting a shadow

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, text, photoshop-effects, layer-style

I want the text printed on a sheet of gold (paper cloth, etc.) look like he cut in scope and is casting a shadow on the surface beneath*. (Say black gray etc) 
So I tried to print text on the slide (transparency sheet) and pinning it above gold paper.
The results were unconvincing... 
What are the best to use functions to format the text that will give maximum results
**Many thanks in advance**
I print the text sizes 13-16 points
use photoshop cs-5

*[image: Design text look like it is cut out and casting a shadow] on the object beneath it.

### Edit

I'll try to clarify my question

I try to imagine hollow letters using digital printing. See Example 1

now for example No. 2 (digital printing).
I  print text on the slide (transparency sheet) and pinning it above gold sheet.
Note that the background color (bronze) beneath the gold sheet, is the same color inside the letters.

This is to the letters are deemed hollow (from the) gold sheet and see through them the background color (Bronze).

My intention is that the observer is convinced the letters are certainly hollow from the gold sheet...

Are there additional functions in Photoshop that I should try
What do you think of the current result?.

Thank you for helping

[image]

[image: I try to imagine hollow letters using digital printing. See Example 1]

Comment: I seriously do not understand what you are trying to do. Are you just trying to overlay a text layer onto a background (gold cloth?)? Are you trying to have the text look embossed into the background? What is the transparency for? Please explain better what you are looking to accomplish.

Comment: I think *anything* you do is going to be "unconvincing". You aren't going to get real world appearances via digital effects. You can only create pseudo appearances on screen. Once you enter the real world, you need real world methods, not digital methods.

Comment: Thank you
I'll try to create examples to explain myself more clear

Comment: The answer from @ACEkin is still what you're looking for. The better your effect will be, the more convincing it will be. That means: soften the inside edges and make them smoother, make some tests with the invert embossing effects and try different shades. Maybe your inner shadow is too dark/dull and not subtle enough; you can use a dark brown instead of black too. You can also use "satin" to add some inner light as the golden example you posted in your edit. There's nice tutorials too and even free layer effects you can get online. Leave some white where you want the gold to appear & shine.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this effect will work for you, see samples below. I realize you can get better gold simulation for the background.

1. Write your text in any color
2. Add your bevel and emboss, in or out effect
3. Change the text layer's Fill option to zero (0)
4. Add drop shadow rather than inner shadow and remove the check mark next to "Layer Knocks Out Drop Shadow"

You will end up with something like the end result you will see. Text will have no color the shadow will be beneath it. Adjust drop shadow distance to taste.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**UPDATE**

Here is another version, I am not sure if you consider close to what you are trying to achieve. The font in use is Georgia Bold and you will find the effect settings in the following screens, I used Bevel and Emboss, Contour, Stroke settings as you will see. The text Fill is set to 0, so the color is not important as I wrote before.

The end result:

[image]

Effect settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]